# Display last 10 characters only

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I am using an EL to display a String in my GSP.

```
${grails.util.Holders.config.dataSource.url}
```

I would like to only display the last ten characters.  Any ideas on how I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
${grails.util.Holders.config.dataSource.url[-10..-1]}
```

See docs: http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1525-Strings

Comment: +1 Or in case of strings less than 10 chars long: `${grails.util.Holders.config.dataSource.url.with { length() ? getAt( -Math.min(10,length())..-1 ) : '' }}` (here's where a taglib would probably be better)