# How to get last 2 digit from a String

Tags: groovy

I have a problem to get last two digit from a string.

example :

```
String texter = "5793231309"
```

how to get '09' ?
so when I`println "texter : "+texter`.
It will be Groovy<<09

I try split but it not successful ?

Comment: I would just add, as it happened to me several times to check string size before performing the [-2..-1] method as it will throw java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Negative array index [-2] too large for array size 1

Comment: Also I think the selected answer should Seagull's as it has more explaination.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display last 10 characters only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134649/display-last-10-characters-only)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use this to split your first String:

```
static main(args) {

    String texter = "5793231309"
    String texter2 = texter[-2..-1]

    println(texter2)
}
```

Comment: can i know what thats mean?
>>> -2 ..-1??

Comment: @akiong In my answer there is a documentation link to this syntax explanation.

Comment: Its like the .substring() method in java. This is just an easier format used in groovy

Answer (score 23):

Here's a one liner that's also a safe alternative:

```
assert "5793231309".reverse().take(2).reverse() == "09"
```

Answer (score 18):

In groovy you can substring via negative indices.

`String last2 = texter[-2..-1] // Last 2 symbols`

Its an analogue of substring, and it uses Ranges.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections see **'Slicing with the subscript operator'**

**Inspired by tim_yates:**

It may be safer to use some function, to extract last n characters, as tim suggested. But I think his solution, with regexp is a big overhead, and may be hard to understand by novices.

There is an easier and faster way to do this, using size() check, and then range substring:

```
def lastN(String input, int n){
  return n > input?.size() ? null : n ? input[-n..-1] : ''
}
assert lastN("Hello", 2) == 'lo'
assert lastN("Hello", 3) == 'llo'
assert lastN("Hello", 0) == ''
assert lastN("Hello", 13) == null
assert lastN(null, 3) == null
```

Comment: @tim_yates Yes. I have noticed that after writing it. When I first noticed regexp, I fall into panic and rush to write non-regexp solution =) Only after it I have read full post, sorry) Should I remove it?

Comment: @Seagull heh, no worries ;-)  I should have put the preferred solution first in my list of 2 ;-)

Comment: That link is dead now. Here is a working one: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html

Answer (score 6):

Be careful though, if your unit is less than 2 characters long, `s[ -2..-1 ]` will fail.

Might be better to do:

```
String lastN( String input, int n ) {
    input == null ?
        null :
        ( input =~ /^.+(\S{$n})$/ ).with { m -> m.matches() ?
                                                    m[ 0 ][ 1 ] :
                                                    null }
}

assert lastN( "5793231309", 2 ) == '09'
assert lastN( "5793231309", 3 ) == '309'
assert lastN( "5793231309", 0 ) == ''
assert lastN( '', 2 ) == null
assert lastN( null, 2 ) == null
```

Or:

```
String lastN( String input, int n ) {
    if( input == null || input.length() < n ) null
    else if( n == 0 ) ''
    else input[ -n..-1 ]
}

assert lastN( "5793231309", 2 ) == '09'
assert lastN( "5793231309", 3 ) == '309'
assert lastN( "5793231309", 0 ) == ''
assert lastN( '', 2 ) == null
assert lastN( null, 2 ) == null
```

Comment: PS:  I'd go for the second version...  If you can avoid regular expressions, you're often better doing so ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Another safe alternative using size() and substring() methods:

> s?.size() < 2 ? s : s.substring(s.size() - 2)

Note the above takes care of nulls and strings that are less than two characters long.

Answer (score 5):

The most readable solution is probably just to `drop()` all but the last two characters:

```
def texter = "5793231309"
println texter.drop(texter.size() - 2)  //result: "09"
```

Or as a reusable closure:

```
def lastTwo = { it.drop(it.size() - 2) }

println lastTwo("ABC")  //result: "BC"
println lastTwo("AB")   //result: "AB"
println lastTwo("A")    //result: "A" (no exception thrown)
println lastTwo("")     //result: ""  (no exception thrown)
```

Fiddle with the code:
https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5768158526832640

More examples of Groovy goodness:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/09/groovy-goodness-take-and-drop-items.html

Answer (score 2):

In `Java` use

```
String texter = "5793231309";
String val=texter.substring(texter.length()-2,texter.length());
System.out.println("val-->"+val);
```

In `Groovy` you don’t need the above stuff just,

```
String value= texter[-2..-1]
```